# How to publish a jar from a Jenkins job in a repository (Jenkins driven) and how does a dependency for that jar should look like?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jar

This is how I create the build: clean compile assembly:single

This is how my pom looks like (at least the jar creation part):

```
<groupId>org.test.qa</groupId>
<artifactId>TheJarName</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
...
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>code.Code</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/java/Main.java</filter>
        </filters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I run the job, the jar is created, all fine, I have it in the workspace.
But, ofc, I want to use it in other projects, as a maven dependency.
I don't have access to create a maven project on the servers, I can only handle things through Jenkins.
I've found this plugin: [Jenkins Maven Repository Server](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=74417177)

That allows me to see my jar here:
http://jenkins.xxx.com/plugin/repository/everything/org/test/qa/Code/1.0-SNAPSHOT/

Which is nice... but does not do too much for me.
And I'm stuck for 2 days.
1) How do I add this jar as a dependency in other poms? Is that even possible?
2) The jenkins link requires (as expected), authorization - is there a way to configure that in a pom file? Is that a good practice (I think not).

Should I look at Artifactory or something like ssh deploy of the jars?
I'm pretty confident that people do this daily...

Comment: the short form is that the POM looking to consume the org.test.qa:TheJarName artifact needs to add http://jenkins.xxx.com/plugin/repository/everything as a repository (either through settings.xml or the consuming POM itself)  https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html (internal repositories section).  NOTE - do NOT add org/text/qa<etc> to the repository URL

Comment: one more thing - if you are able to setup an Artifactory or Nexus server (treating it as an organization-wide system), by all means do so.  The plugin you're using that exposes Jenkins build artifacts as a Maven repository works, but an asset management server just works better (especially when combined w/ the Jenkins plugins that will automatically publish artifacts...and complete build info...out to Artifactory)